# Intuition behind simple matrix multiplication property

Tags: matrices

I'm having trouble understanding the following matrix multiplication property. $$U * V^T = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(v_i * u^t_i)$$
I get it that if expand this multiplication and write each element of resulting matrix as dot products I would get the same if I would sum up right side matrices but is there simple more intuitive way of showing this equation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $\textbf{U}$ and $\textbf{V}^T$ as "stacks of vectors" if you want.

$$\textbf{U} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{u}_1^t \\ \vdots \\ \textbf{u}_n^t
\end{bmatrix},
\textbf{V} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{v}_1^t \\ \vdots \\ \textbf{v}_n^t
\end{bmatrix}, 
\textbf{V}^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{v}_1 & .. &  \textbf{v}_n
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
where the $t$ next the the vector just indicates that it is a row vector (vectors without the $t$ are column vectors). Then
$$
\textbf{U} \textbf{V}^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{u}_1^t \\ \vdots \\ \textbf{u}_n^t
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{v}_1 & .. &  \textbf{v}_n
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{u}_1^t \cdot \textbf{v}_1 & ... & \textbf{u}_1^t \cdot \textbf{v}_n \\
\vdots & & \vdots \\
\textbf{u}_n^t \cdot \textbf{v}_1 & ... & \textbf{u}_n^t \cdot \textbf{v}_n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now try a similar exercise by writing the sum out and compare the two.